# Node is not accessible from hub in selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

I just started the hub on my local machine using the following command.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role hub
```

it started successfully, then I have tried to connect a node to another machine using the following command.

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=d:\sel\new\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar  -role  node -port 5566 -hub http://"HUbip":4444/grid/register
```

it has shown me The node is registered to the hub and ready to use in the console.

but when I opened `Http://"HUbip":4444/grid/console` it has shown the IP and 5 chrome browser, 5 Firefox, 1 internet explorer logos. But at the top of that, the text has shown like "DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version, Failed to connect to Ip of the node".
so when I have tried to run the test I am getting an error like "Could not start a new session. Possible causes are the invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: `version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'"`.

I have already switched off both machine's firewall. and tried to telnet from the node to hub, it was a success.
I am unable to rectify the issue. someone, please suggest a solution.

Comment: when I connected a node from the same machine it was working fine.

Comment: Update the question with the binary version info you are using and the log/error stack traces for _Hub_ and _Node_

Comment: Give some more info. Detailed stack trace, which version of selenium-server, and are sessions expired. Check if Your drivers are up to date, with selenium server or vice versa.

Comment: @KovacicI am using updated versions of selenium drivers which are 3.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

Add in [Selenium Grid Extras](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras) which can help you with the management of Selenium Grid like :

1. Restart the node/hub
2. Clear session
3. Recommends the defaults for the ports

You'll need to run the setup on the hub and node:

```
java -jar SeleniumGridExtras-*.*.*-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Note: You're not using the standard port for the node 5555.

Comment: even if I used different ports including 5555 still the issue persists.